# Traffic Simulation Java opposite side

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on java project that shown in the photo , So i faced a problem with the car moving in the road its working from left to right , but what i need 3-sides left to right and another 3-sides from right to left i also want to move the buttons down show in green color.

So how to solve it?

The code:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    
    public class Traffic implements ActionListener, Runnable {
        
        JFrame frame= new JFrame("Traffic Simulation");
        Road road = new Road();
        //south container
        JButton start=new JButton("Start");
        JButton stop=new JButton("stop");
        JLabel result = new JLabel("result:0");
        Container south=new Container();
        
        //west container
        JButton semi=new JButton("Add semi");
        JButton suv=new JButton("Add SUV");
        JButton sports=new JButton("Add Sports");
        
        Container west=new Container();
        
        //east container 
        
        JButton truck=new JButton("Add Truck");
        JButton motorbike=new JButton("Add motorbike");
        JButton car=new JButton("Add car");
        
        Container east=new Container();
        
        boolean running=false;
        int carcount =0;
        long startTime = 0;
        
        public Traffic() {
            frame.setSize(2000,1000);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(road, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            
            south.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3)); 
            //adding actionlistener to star/stop buttons
            south.add(start);
            start.addActionListener(this);
            south.add(stop);
            stop.addActionListener(this);
            south.add(result);
            frame.add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            
            
            west.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 1));                              // Button 
            // adding actionListener to car buttons
            west.add(semi);
            semi.addActionListener(this); 
            west.add(suv);
            suv.addActionListener(this);
            west.add(sports);
            sports.addActionListener(this);
            
            frame.add(east, BorderLayout.WEST);
            
            east.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 1));                              // Button 
            // adding actionListener to car buttons
            sports.addActionListener(this);
            east.add(truck);
            sports.addActionListener(this);
            east.add(motorbike);
            sports.addActionListener(this);
            east.add(car);
            sports.addActionListener(this);
            
            frame.add(west, BorderLayout.EAST);
            
            
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            
            frame.repaint();
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Traffic();
             
        }
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (event.getSource().equals(start)) {
                if(running == false) {
                    running=true;
                    road.resetcarcount();
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    Thread t=new Thread(this);
                    t.start();
                }
                
            }
            if (event.getSource().equals(stop)) {
                running=false;
            }
            
            if (event.getSource().equals(semi)) {
                Semi semi= new Semi(0, 20);
                road.addCar(semi);
                for (int x=0;x<road.ROAD_WIDTH; x=x+20) {
                    for(int y=20;y<600;y=y+150) { 
                        semi.setx(x);
                        semi.sety(y);
                        if(road.collision(x, y, semi)==false) {
                            frame.repaint();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            if (event.getSource().equals(suv)) {
                SUV suv= new SUV (0, 20);
                road.addCar(suv);
                for (int x=0;x<road.ROAD_WIDTH; x=x+40) {
                    for(int y=20;y<600;y=y+150) { 
                        suv.setx(x);
                        suv.sety(y);
                        if(road.collision(x, y, suv)==false) {
                            frame.repaint();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            if (event.getSource().equals(sports)) {
                Sports sports= new Sports (0, 20);
                road.addCar(sports);
                for (int x=0;x<road.ROAD_WIDTH; x=x+20) {
                    for(int y=20;y<600;y=y+150) { 
                        sports.setx(x);
                        sports.sety(y);
                        if(road.collision(x, y, sports)==false) {
                            frame.repaint();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(running==true) {
                road.step();
                carcount =road.getCarCount();
                double resultCalc= carcount / (1000 * (double)(System.currentTimeMillis()) - startTime);
                result.setText("result:"+resultCalc);
                frame.repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Program Interface]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Welcome to SO. 1. No need to `sports.addActionListener(this);` 5 times. 2. Swing is a single Thread library. Running long processes (such as sleep) on the Event Dispatcher Thread  ([EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html))
keeps this thread busy, so it does not do other things 
like updating the gui. The gui becomes unresponsive (freezes). Use a Swing `Timer` as an animation driver.

Comment: You have everything in one class.  Create a plain Java getter / setter Vehicle class to hold the values (vehicle type, X position, color, etc.) for each type of vehicle.  Create a plain Java getter / setter Road class to hold a java.util.List of Vehicle instances.  Create a drawing JPanel where you draw the road and vehicles based on the values in the Road and Vehicle model classes.  Use a Swing Timer to animate the vehicles on the road.

Comment: Thank you , but i didn't find the answer about moving the cars from right to left in (green) photo so how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

1. To fix your problem, add 3 blank components (like `new JComponent()`) to your panel in the right before adding the real buttons, so the buttons will show up in the bottom of your `JFrame`'s `BorderLayout.EAST`.
2. You are mixing between sides, you add the `west` panel to `BorderLayout.EAST` and `east` panel to `BorderLayout.WEST`, please change it to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I already fix that but my issue currently the vehicles moves from one side I want to split it